# Vba code with =sum

Tags: excel, sum, vba

I'm using the following

```
Sub CopyDataByDay()
    Dim data As Range
    Dim today As Date

    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    today = Date

    If (Weekday(today) = vbMonday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbTuesday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbWednesday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbThursday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbFriday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbSaturday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B6") = data.Value
    End If

    data.Value = ""
End Sub
```

But in `A1` I have a `=sum` that gets removed every time I use this VBA. How do I stop the `=sum` in `A1` getting removed?

Comment: Well you're explicitly clearing your `A1` with `data.Value = ""`, what else should be happening?

Comment: Just a general note, your code is "screaming" for `Select Case` instead of your multiple `If` and `ElseIf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need remove this line

> data.Value = ""

Comment: Thank you I have just started using VBA I will do that.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not an attempt** to answer the question as @Vahid has already pointed out what the problem is. This is more of a `pointer` on how to write concise code.

Here is the shortest way to write your code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim data As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set data = .Range("A1")

        For i = 2 To 7
            If Weekday(Date) = i Then .Range("B" & i - 1) = data.Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the value of `vbMonday` is 2 and `vbSaturday` is 7. So you can actually write a loop for it.

Had it been a very big loop, the line

```
If Weekday(Date) = i Then .Range("B" & i - 1) = data.Value
```

can also be written as

```
If Weekday(Date) = i Then .Range("B" & i - 1) = data.Value: Exit For
```

Comment: That is [not a good loop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793/). All you need is `if Weekday(Date) <> vbSunday then .Range("B1").Offset(Weekday(Date) - 2).Value = data.Value`.

Comment: I will check out the link but the code you gave is even better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to always define and referencing your Sheet object.
Also, using `Select Case`, simplifies it a lot:

```
Sub CopyDataByDay()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim data As Range
Dim today As Date

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set data = sht.Range("A1")
today = Date

With sht

    Select Case Weekday(today)
        Case vbMonday
            .Range("B1") = data.Value

        Case vbTuesday
            .Range("B2") = data.Value

        Case vbWednesday
            .Range("B3") = data.Value

        Case vbThursday
            .Range("B4") = data.Value

        Case vbFriday
            .Range("B5") = data.Value

        Case vbSaturday
            .Range("B6") = data.Value

    End Select

End With

End Sub
```